# Uncheck check box when dropdown selection changes - not working

Tags: javascript, html

In a MVC website, how do you make a check box unchecked if a dropdown list has changed value? I'm not sure if MVC behaves differently form traditional asp.Net application but what I coded does not work.

In default.aspx I have a JavaScript function:

```
function UncheckFooBox() {
   var isChecked = document.getElementById("cbxFoo").checked;
        if (isChecked)
            document.getElementById("cbxFoo").checked = true;
```

then

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxFoo" runat="server" 
     checked="checked" id="cbxFoo" />Foo
```

then below all this I have the dropdown list

```
<select Name="FooChecker" onchange="UncheckFooBox()" >
    <option value="1" >Yes</option>
    <option value="2" >No</option>
    <option value="0"> </option>
</select>
```

So the outcome should be that if I change the selection of the FooChecker, the cbxFoo is checked, it will uncheck it on the client side, can't have a post back at this point just yet. - thanks!

Please note that jQuery is not really an option at this time. (I know, I should learn it...)

Comment: Did you mean to set `.checked` to `false` instead of `true`?

Comment: Did you try accessing the 'checked' attribute as an attribute - using getAttribute('checked') and setAttribute('checked') rather than as a property/field ?

Comment: @David, It is checked by default. If I change dropdown's value I want the checkbox unchecked.

Comment: Okay, I'll just go in the closet and hide in shame: @David, that's what was wrong with it. Feel free to post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function UncheckFooBox() {
     var elem = document.getElementById("cbxFoo");
     var isChecked = elem.getAttribute('checked');
    if(isChecked) 
        elem.removeAttribute('checked');
    }
```

Comment: @David's comment above was correct, I should have checked my code. Thanks for your post!